# Problem with footnote hyperlinks and package setspace

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, hyperlink

Recently I've switched from pdflatex compiler to lualatex and got following problem: every footnote hyperlink throws me to the last page of the document. At the same time, everything is perfect with usual (label) links. I've tried to create a small example showing this problem, but preamble of my document is way too big, and just with hyperref package everything works fine. Is there any general reason why some problem like this could happen?

**Upd.** I managed to (thanks to @Marijn comment) understand, that the problem was with setspace package (and lualatex has nothing to do with that). I don't know what exactly is wrong, but placing \usepackage{setspace} before \usepackage{hyperref} solves the problem.

Comment: Try to reduce the preamble one package at the time (and delete any content in the document that uses the package that you remove from the preamble) until the problem disappears. Then you know which package is respronsible. Then try to remove other packages and check if the problem persists. Once you have isolated the problematic package then you can make a minimal example.

Comment: @Marijn, thanks, it was a really good advice.

Comment: there are _very_ few packages that should be loaded after `hyperref` and those do say so in their manual. For all other cases the rule is: load `hyperref` as last package